How to update Superset with Docker?
I got Superset ver 2.1.3.
I've checked versions on Github. So I pretty sure, that I got old version.
How to update it to last version with Docker?
I use this commands (from directory with Superset data), but still have same version.
docker compose down

docker pull apache/superset:latest

docker run -v superset_data:/path/to/superset/data -d --name superset apache/superset

docker compose up

I got this message:

But after that I get many messages with same status:

That am I doing wrong?

My previous code do not change version of Superset.
Second I'd run compose wrong.
To update Superset with Docker I need:

change Superset ver in filepath/superset/docker-compose.yml with any editor;
stop docker-compose:


docker compose -f /filepath/superset/docker-compose.yml down


run docker-compose in background:


docker compose -f /filepath/superset/docker-compose.yml up -d

